# Angularjs Custom Directive ng-click not working

Tags: angularjs

i've created a custom directive in angularjs:

```
directives.directive('myTop',function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
}
})
```

Directive's code:

```
<div class="my-header">
<button ng-click="alert('x')" class="fa fa-chevron-left"></button>
<h1>SpeakZ</h1>
</div>
```

for some reason, ng-click doesen't trigger.

I searched over the internet and found that compile / link is the solution for this problem,
but I can't seem to reach a working solution.

I am not using jquery..

Comment: alert is not working inside `ng-click` instead it will seach for `$scope.alert` function in the scope

Comment: originally I tried putting:
     $location.path('/')
inside ng-click.. dosen't work

Comment: that is `$location` does not exist in the `$scope`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to add a `link` function to the directive definition for this to work. So basically,

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

app.directive('myTop',function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<button ng-click="clickFunc()">CLICK</button>',
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.clickFunc = function () {
            alert('Hello, world!');
        };
    }
}
})
```

And the html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <my-top></my-top>
</div>
```

And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4otpd8ah/

Comment: What do you mean by native functions?

Comment: originally I tried putting:
     $location.path('/')
inside ng-click.. doesn't work

Comment: That will not work. You should have a function defined in the scope of the directive (in the case above its scope.clickFunc) which does something depending on what you'd need. `$location` will also need to be injected into the directive.

Comment: That worked for me but how can i attach a function that is already defined in the scope??

Answer (score 1):

Either use link as answered by @Ashesh or just simply add scope. If you set scope false you will not have isolated scope and click will work on directive.

```
directives.directive('myTop',function($compile) {
return {
   restrict: 'EA',
   scope: false,
   templateUrl: 'views/header.html',
  }
})
```