# Unable to call parent controller method from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I've seen the [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440964/angularjs-custom-directive-ng-click-not-working), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488769/ng-click-doesnt-work-within-the-template-of-a-directive), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567383/why-doesnt-ng-click-work-in-my-directive-and-how-do-i-add-a-toggle-class), [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363217/angularjs-accessing-ng-click-in-custom-directive) questions on this problem but for some reason I *still* can't bind `ng-click` in my directive to a method on the parent controller. I'm pretty sure I've got my scope isolation and method parameter passing right but no luck so far. A gross simplification (this app is huge) of my JS looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').directive('myCustomDirective', customDirective);

function customDirective() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myCallback: '&myCallback'
    }
    template: '<div><h3>My directive</h3><p>I am item {{itemIndex}}</p><button ng-click="myCallback({itemIndex: itemIndex})">Click to call back</button></div>'
  }
}

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);

function myController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.selectedIndex = -1;

  vm.items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

  vm.callbackMethod = function(itemIndex) {
    vm.selectedIndex = itemIndex;
  }
}
```

and the similarly simplified markup looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="myController as test">
      <p>Selected item: {{test.selectedIndex}}</p>
      <my-custom-directive my-callback="test.callbackMethod" ng-repeat="item in test.items" ng-init="itemIndex = $index"></my-custom-directive>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I'm at a loss here as I've followed every SO post and blog on the subject and still nothing. Just to make things worse, the [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/D8HrZSRH06cfasFJgMBk?p=preview) I made to illustrate this problem also doesn't work (`$injector:nomod`) - bonus points if anyone can spot why! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define method with parameter, rather than putting it reference on directive element.

```
my-callback="test.callbackMethod(itemIndex)"
```

Also do pass current element index to directive by adding it in isolated scope.

```
scope: {
  myCallback: '&myCallback',
  itemIndex: '='
},
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/kAvIioJdpbV9fkDNvw2J?p=preview)

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35467378/2435473)

Answer (score 1):

I added an extra attribute to your directive and removed the ng-init.

```
 <my-custom-directive my-callback="test.callbackMethod($index)" ng-repeat="item in test.items track by $index" theindex="$index"></my-custom-directive>
```

[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y5KSQ99mh46wQjvPl5DM?p=info)